# From character vector back to VCorpus

Tags: r, tm, corpus

I have a VCorpus, which is extracted like this:

```
corp <- VCorpus(DirSource("//Filepath"))
```

I then wanted to delete certain rows from my files within the Corpus that contained a certain word. To do this I converted my Corpus to `as.character`:

```
corp <- sapply(corp, as.character)
```

and then removed all rows including the word FILE:

```
for(j in seq(corp)) {
  corp[[j]] <- corp[[j]][!grepl("FILE", corp[[j]], ignore.case = FALSE)]
}
```

Now I want to go back to the class "VCorpus" to use tm_map to perform Corpus cleaning tasks like:

```
corp <- tm_map(corp, content_transformer(tolower))
corp <- tm_map(corp, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
corp <- tm_map(corp, removePunctuation)
corp <- tm_map(corp, removeNumbers)
```

But I get the following error message:

> Error in UseMethod("tm_map", x) :    no applicable method for 'tm_map'
>   applied to an object of class "list"

I have tried several things but I get error messages like:

> Error in UseMethod("as.VCorpus") :    no applicable method for
>   'as.VCorpus' applied to an object of class "character"

Any ideas how I can transform back to VCorpus and perform tm_map tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should be setting the corpus to `as.character`, as it destroys the meta data that makes it a corpus.  The text is already contained, for element `i` of your corpus, in `corp[[i]]$content`, so you would be better off just working with this directly.

A workflow that works for me would be...

```
corp <- VCorpus(DirSource("//Filepath"))

for(j in seq(corp)) {
    corp[[j]]$content <- corp[[j]]$content[!grepl("FILE", corp[[j]]$content,ignore.case = FALSE)]
}

corp <- tm_map(corp, content_transformer(tolower))
...etc
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew this was exactly what I needed!